# Resultant of two polynomials in two variables

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have two polynomials in two variables. 
$$f= nx^n+(n-1)x^{n-1}y+(n-2)x^{n-2}y^2+...+xy^{n-1}-c$$
$$g= x^{n-1}y+2x^{n-2}y^2+3x^{n-3}y^3+..+(n-1)xy^{n-1}+ny^n-d$$

Where $c$ and $d$ are some constants.
So I am making the resultant of the polynomials in $x$. Right then we have a nice $(2n-1)\times (2n-1)$ matrix that has $y$'s in it. I am trying to show that the determinant of this resultant matrix is a polynomial in therms of $y$ that has degree $n^2$ but this is proving to be very hard. Clearly the diagonal gives a something in terms of $y$ that is of degree $n^2$ but there are other ways to make terms of that degree how do I know they do not kill each other. I would appreciate a fresh set of eyes with an Idea that I can pursue

Comment: A few test cases in Mathematica suggest that, if $m$ is the parameter in $f$, and $n$ the parameter in $g$, then the degree of $y$ in the resultant is $mn$. This is perhaps not surprising, but it may still be worth mentioning.

Comment: Interestingly, for $n=1, 2, 3, \dots, 10$, the coefficient of the leading term is $\left( n(n+1) \right)^{n-1}$.